# ggplot2 path colour getting multiple paths when only want one

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot a set of points connected with one path like in the first plot below, but with the colour set by whether the X is increasing or decreasing by using the `adf$up` flag as in the second plot.

However, when I try combining the two as in the third plot, I get two separate paths rather than a single path through all the points.

```
# hysteresis plotting in ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
N <- 20
adf <- data.frame(X=rnorm(N), Y=rnorm(N))
adf$up <- c(FALSE, diff(adf$X)>0 )
qplot(X, Y, data=adf, geom=c('point', 'path'))          # plot 1
qplot(X, Y, data=adf, col=up, geom='point')             # plot 2
qplot(X, Y, data=adf, col=up, geom=c('point', 'path'))  # plot 3
```

I can nearly get what I want by using a real value for colour as in plot 4 - but I would prefer a binary colour.

```
adf$diff <- c(0, diff(adf$X))
qplot(X, Y, data=adf, col=diff, geom=c('point', 'path'))   # plot 4
```

How do I get a binary colour for `adf$up` for the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable that is `-1` for negative values and `1` for positive value and then use a continuous colour scale :

```
adf$diff2 <- sign(adf$diff)
qplot(X, Y, data=adf, col=diff2, geom=c('point', 'path')) + scale_colour_gradient2(low="red",mid="black",high="green", guide="none")
```

Of course, you'll get a black line when diff is 0... (but you can later modify this value if you want the line to be green or red)

Comment: Great @CathG that's exactly it! FYI I can say `adf$diff2 <- sign(adf$diff)` to get -1/0/+1.

Comment: @Sean, thanks for the tip, I edited my answer to modify the "creation" of diff2. (Actually, I knew this function, I don't know why I didn't think of using it...)